# Message notification is blocked while running game

Tags: android, notifications, libgdx

I have built a small game by libgdx. This game runs smoothly on Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 7, without any problems. But when I test it on LG Optimus Me P350 (which has 256Mb of RAM), some times while playing it cannot receive messages, sometimes it can receive messages but without notification, and sometimes it receives normally. And when I am not playing this game, it always receives message notifications normally. I have no idea what the reason might be. Does anybody have any clue?

Comment: Plug it in and check the logcat.

Comment: Low memory is probably the issue, I agree with 323go, check the logcat.